# Iteration on maximum of uniform distribution

Tags: probability

Set $x = 0$. Iterate $x := \operatorname{max}(a, b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are I.I.D. random samples from the continuous uniform distribution $U(x,1)$. What is the probability distribution of $x$ after $k$ iterations? I was able to derive the probability density function after 1 iteration as $f(x) = 2x, 0 < x < 1$.

Comment: much easier to say the expected value is $1-\dfrac{1}{3^k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_k$ be the random variable obtained on the $k^{\rm th}$ iteration, so $X_0 = 0$.  Next, consider $$X_{k+1} \mid X_k$$ which is simply the maximum order statistic of two IID observations drawn from a uniform distribution on $(X_k, 1)$.  That is to say, $$\Pr[\max(a,b) \le x \mid X_k] = \Pr[a \le x \mid X_k]\Pr[b \le x \mid X_k],$$ or $$F_{X_{k+1} \mid X_k}(x) = \left(\frac{x-X_k}{1-X_k}\right)^2, \quad X_k \le x \le 1.$$  Consequently, $$f_{X_{k+1} \mid X_k}(x) = \frac{2(x-X_k)}{(1-X_k)^2}, \quad X_k \le x \le 1.$$  This means, for example, $$f_{X_1}(x) = f_{X_1 \mid X_0}(x) = 2x, \quad 0 \le x \le 1,$$ and $$\begin{align*} f_{X_2}(x) &= \int_{x_1 = 0}^x f_{X_2 \mid X_1 = x_1}(x) f_{X_1}(x_1) \, dx_1 \\
&= \int_{x_1=0}^x \frac{2(x-x_1)}{(1-x_1)^2} 2x_1 \, dx_1 \\
&= 4(x-2)\log(1-x) - 8x, \quad 0 < x < 1. \end{align*}$$

We can see that this will quickly become computationally difficult:
$$\begin{align*}f_{X_3}(x) &= \int_{x_2=0}^x f_{X_3 \mid X_2 = x_2} (x) f_{X_2}(x_2) \, dx_2 \\
&= 4 \left(12 x - 6 (x-2) \log (1-x) + x \log^2(1-x)\right).\end{align*}$$

Continuing with the benefit of computers, $$f_{X_4}(x) = \frac{8}{3} \left(-120 x+(x-2) \log ^3(1-x)-12 x \log ^2(1-x)+60 (x-2) \log (1-x)\right).$$

In general, $$f_{X_{k+1}}(x) = \int_{x_k=0}^x f_{X_{k+1} \mid X_k = x_k}(x) f_{X_k}(x_k) \, dx_k.$$  There may be a pattern in the terms; indeed we can speculate that there is a general form $$a_0 x + \sum_{n=1}^k a_k (x-1+(-1)^k) \log^k (1-x)$$ for suitable coefficients $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 0}$.